# angular calculation for each item

Tags: angular

I'm developing a prototype for CPQ (Configuration Pricing Quotation system). There is a multi step form: 1. selecting a customer and providing contract details etc. 2. selecting rateplans and 3. adjusting the price.

In step three I'm displaying the list price for each seleted rateplan.
I need to call a function when there is a discount entered to calculate the individual price for each item based on following parameters:
Scenario 1: listprice - discount % (*quantity [optional]) = total for this.item
Scenario 2: listprice - discount (absolute) (*quantity [optional]) = total for this item
--> there are two or three fields that should trigger an update: discount absolute, discount % and maybe quantity (depends on product type).

I wrote a function to calculate the price based on discount % is below as well as the related HTML code
FUNCTION in TS

```
  discountpercentage(price: number, discountP: number) {
    this.total = +price - (+price * +discountP / 100);
  }
```

HTML

```
 <div>
      <span>PRODUCT RATE PLAN</span>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <div *ngFor="let product of orderIntake">
        <br />
        <span class="rightpadding"><b>Product:</b> {{ product.productName }}</span><span class="rightpadding"><b>Rate plan:</b> {{ product.productRatePlans.name }}</span>
        <table class="subtable">
          <tr class="header"><th>CHARGE NAME</th><th>TYPE</th><th>MODEL</th><th>UOM</th><th>PRICE</th><th>DISCOUNT AMOUNT</th><th>DISCOUNT PERCENTAGE</th><th>QUANTITY</th><th>TOTAL</th></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="11"><mat-divider></mat-divider></td></tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let rateplancharge of product?.productRatePlans.productRatePlanCharges">
            <td>{{ rateplancharge.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ rateplancharge.type }}</td>
            <td>{{ rateplancharge.model }}</td>
            <td>{{ rateplancharge.uom }}</td>
            <td>
              <table>
                <tr *ngFor="let price of rateplancharge.pricing | currencyFilter : 'USD'">
                  <td>{{ price.price }}<span matSuffix>.00 {{ price.currency }}</span></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table>
                <tr *ngFor="let price of rateplancharge.pricing | currencyFilter : 'USD'">
                  <td><mat-form-field appearance="outline"><input matInput placeholder="Discount" min="0" max="maxDiscount(100)" ng-change="discountpercentage()" value="0" type="number" ng-model="discount" style="text-align: right"><span matSuffix>.00</span></mat-form-field></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table>
                <tr *ngFor="let price of rateplancharge.pricing | currencyFilter : 'USD'">
                  <td><mat-form-field appearance="outline"><input matInput placeholder="Discount %" min="0" max="10" (change)="discountpercentage(price.price, discountP.value)" value="0" type="number" style="text-align: right" #discountP><span matSuffix>.00 %</span></mat-form-field></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table>
                <tr *ngFor="let price of rateplancharge.pricing | currencyFilter : 'USD'">
                  <td style="text-align: center"><span *ngIf="!rateplancharge['defaultQuantity']">N.A.</span><mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="rateplancharge.defaultQuantity"><input matInput placeholder="Quantity" min="0" (change)="priceCalc()" value="{{ rateplancharge.defaultQuantity }}" type="number" ng-model="quantity" style="text-align: right"></mat-form-field></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>{{ total }}</td>
          </tr>
        </table><br />
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>

      </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is the total for each different line item is the same. I don't know how to separate the total for each item. 
How can I calculate the total individually for each item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish your goal would be getting rid of the `total` variable entirely, and replacing it in your template with a function that outputs the correct total value based on the inputs. So, you could change this:

```
{{total}}
```

with something like this:

```
{{getTotal(price, discountPercentage)}}
```

Or, you can expand your `total` variable into an array of arrays and use it like this:

```
  discountpercentage(price: number, discountP: number, productIndex: number, ratePlanChargeIndex: number) 
  {
    this.total[productIndex][ratePlanChargeIndex] = +price - (+price * +discountP / 100);
  }
```

And in your template, you would need to pass the `productIndex` and `ratePlanChargeIndex` anywhere that you are calling the `discountpercentage` function like this:

```
<div>
      <span>PRODUCT RATE PLAN</span>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <div *ngFor="let product of orderIntake; let productIndex = index">
        <br />
        <span class="rightpadding"><b>Product:</b> {{ product.productName }}</span><span class="rightpadding"><b>Rate plan:</b> {{ product.productRatePlans.name }}</span>
        <table class="subtable">
          <tr class="header"><th>CHARGE NAME</th><th>TYPE</th><th>MODEL</th><th>UOM</th><th>PRICE</th><th>DISCOUNT AMOUNT</th><th>DISCOUNT PERCENTAGE</th><th>QUANTITY</th><th>TOTAL</th></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="11"><mat-divider></mat-divider></td></tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let rateplancharge of product?.productRatePlans.productRatePlanCharges; let ratePlanChargeIndex = index">
            <td>{{ rateplancharge.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ rateplancharge.type }}</td>
            <td>{{ rateplancharge.model }}</td>
            <td>{{ rateplancharge.uom }}</td>
            <td>
              <table>
                <tr *ngFor="let price of rateplancharge.pricing | currencyFilter : 'USD'">
                  <td>{{ price.price }}<span matSuffix>.00 {{ price.currency }}</span></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table>
                <tr *ngFor="let price of rateplancharge.pricing | currencyFilter : 'USD'">
                  <td><mat-form-field appearance="outline"><input matInput placeholder="Discount" min="0" max="maxDiscount(100)" ng-change="discountpercentage(0, 0, productIndex, ratePlanChargeIndex)" value="0" type="number" ng-model="discount" style="text-align: right"><span matSuffix>.00</span></mat-form-field></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table>
                <tr *ngFor="let price of rateplancharge.pricing | currencyFilter : 'USD'">
                  <td><mat-form-field appearance="outline"><input matInput placeholder="Discount %" min="0" max="10" (change)="discountpercentage(price.price, discountP.value, productIndex, ratePlanChargeIndex)" value="0" type="number" style="text-align: right" #discountP><span matSuffix>.00 %</span></mat-form-field></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table>
                <tr *ngFor="let price of rateplancharge.pricing | currencyFilter : 'USD'">
                  <td style="text-align: center"><span *ngIf="!rateplancharge['defaultQuantity']">N.A.</span><mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="rateplancharge.defaultQuantity"><input matInput placeholder="Quantity" min="0" (change)="priceCalc()" value="{{ rateplancharge.defaultQuantity }}" type="number" ng-model="quantity" style="text-align: right"></mat-form-field></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>{{ total }}</td>
          </tr>
        </table><br />
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>

      </div>
    </div>
```